# If you receive a gift is that scamming anyone?

Tags: police

I am on Facebook in a group where it’s sharing so meaning people give away or share with the public things they don’t need and give it away as gifts! This lady I met with told the group that I scammed her and other people asking them for gifts when she’s the only one who gave me a gift from that group. The administration then posted that I am scammer and posted my photos and kids photos without my permission to destroy my reputation she basically set me up! Mind you I really needed the help or would’ve never asked to begin with. Even if other people from the group offered to help why not that’s what the group was designed for. I didn’t commit a crime she gave me the “gift” which means I didn’t take it so. People have bad intentions though. They tried to call the police but I spoke to a officer yesterday and he said it was a gift so it’s fine. They can’t file a police report if it’s a gift. This just bothers me.

Comment: You may have grounds to seek recompense due to slander or libel laws.  If it really bothers you, talk to a lawyer.  Most will at least see if you have a case for free.

Comment: Yes I will call a pro bono lawyer to see what my options are since this is such a horrible situation to be in. The police said just delete block and delete account and log on to Facebook in the future but that since it was a “gift” it’s not wrong!! I don’t even want the gift and will not use it. Her intentions were bad! I was set up too. She wrongly judged me too

Comment: I feel like you're missing a couple of sentences here, because it's very difficult to tell what you're saying. You write that you "would’ve never asked to begin with," but it looks like you forgot to tell us *what* you asked. Are you saying that the lady said that you scammed her *by* asking for gifts? If so, that doesn't seem to make sense, since asking for gifts isn't a scam. When you write "I didn't take it," do you mean "I didn't steal it"? If you could edit your question to clarify all these things, that would be really helpful.

Comment: Tanner Swett: Sorry to clarify I am part of a Facebook group and a lady offered to buy my older two daughters a gift card to target for $15 each and my youngest daughter a doll and puzzle well the group is designed to help people in need and not judge. Doesn’t matter what the need is Christmas gifts high chairs strollers rugs kitchen stuff help with anything. For free. Well the lady who offered me the gift and gave me the gift told the Facebook administrator of the group that I scammed her because I drive a new car which isn’t brand new but that’s irrelevant and so on.  false allegations

Comment: Tanner: So the group administrator posted a post in the group calling me a scammer utilizing my photos and my kids photos online without my consent. Posting lies about me. It was clearly a gift however I was set up and the woman who gave me the gift had bad intentions she tried to say I drive a new car and just nasty judge mental things about me when nobody knows me. I truly did need the gift since we are struggling at the moment. However I don’t want it now. This is not a scam if it’s a gift.

Answer (score 3):

Nobody know what constitutes "scamming", because it's not a legal concept. There is no sense in which receiving a gift itself constitutes "scamming". Since scamming is vaguely about dishonesty, there is an imaginable scenario where you could be liable for a false representation, for example if you impersonated someone else in order to receive something of value, you could be prosecuted in [California](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=PEN&sectionNum=528.5). You should not assume that a police officer saying "That's not our problem" is proof that you committed no crime or civil tort. Your lawyer can give you advice as to whether you have anything to worry about, legally.

The other stuff about being called a scammer or having pictures posted might be a violation of Facebook's TOS, and you can always complain to Facebook central authorities. Technically, uploading a picture that someone took is a violation of copyright law, if you didn't give permission to do so. It might run afoul of some state~provincial or national privacy law, depending on where this takes place.

Comment: I understand I never impersonated anyone. I just asked for help which is what the group is for. I was judged wrongly and defamation of character and slander and accused of being a scammer wrongly! Then had other people commenting when they offered me the help so I feel like I was set up by this one woman she had bad intentions. I am in Florida State. I hate my photos and daughters photos to be posted online to complete strangers. This woman basically lied and told the group administrator that I scammed her. I can sue for this